# How to query the proc file system programmatically and equivalently on Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, posix

I am working on an implementation where I would need to store the entry point of every function visited in a hashmap. In order to create an effective hash function, I would need to know the minimum and maximum possible function entry point when a program is already loaded in memory.

What would be the ideal way to do this programmatically (possibly both on Windows and Linux) such that a program can possibly determine its minimum and maximum function entry points that is already loaded in memory.

I was thinking that may be I should query the loading address of the process and determine the process size, but on a second though, a process size may include stack and heap sizes which would be meaningless for me.

Probably what I am looking for is possibly `/proc/<processid>/maps`, so for linux the question might be, how to query the proc file system programmatically and what is the equivalent approach for windows?

Comment: /proc is a file system like any other. Open the file and read it.

Comment: @Arkadiy Problem is, such doesn't exist on windows.

Comment: Assume for a minute you're addressing Windows developers who don't touch *nix...What is `/proc/<processid>/maps`, what does it do, and what do you want to get out of it? Chances are you want to start with something like PSAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to access this information on Windows, but on Linux I see the following from `man proc` :

```
   /proc/[pid]/maps
      A file containing the currently mapped memory regions and their access permissions.

      The format is:

      address           perms offset  dev   inode   pathname
      08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
      08056000-08058000 rw-p 0000d000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
      08058000-0805b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
      40000000-40013000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
      40013000-40015000 rw-p 00012000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
      4001f000-40135000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
      40135000-4013e000 rw-p 00115000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
      4013e000-40142000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
      bffff000-c0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0

      where "address" is the address space in the process that it occupies, "perms" is  a  set  of  permis-
      sions:

           r = read
           w = write
           x = execute
           s = shared
           p = private (copy on write)

      "offset"  is the offset into the file/whatever, "dev" is the device (major:minor), and "inode" is the
      inode on that device.  0 indicates that no inode is associated with the memory region,  as  the  case
      would be with BSS (uninitialized data).

      Under Linux 2.0 there is no field giving pathname.
```

You open the file, you parse it (possibly using fscanf), you look for segments with 'x' permission May be also w/o 'w'). Those are the addresses where functions can be found.